# Original Taylor Swift song Bad Blood

Tags: taylor-swift

So the original song *Bad Blood* without Kendrick Lamar did what I thought could never happen- that is, it was a real song, and now it's impossible to find. Like, you can't even buy it anywhere.

Was the original song ever published on a CD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the album version of "Bad Blood", which can be found on T. Swift's *1989*, doesn't have Kendrick Lamar on it. It seems the single version of the song is a remix with Kendrick Lamar. This seems to be confirmed in the [Wikipedia for *1989*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_(Taylor_Swift_album)). An excerpt from [the relevant section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_(Taylor_Swift_album)#Singles), emphasis mine:

> Both the fourth single "Bad Blood" and its music video were released on May 17, 2015, with the latter premiering at the opening of the 2015 Billboard Music Awards. The music video features many of Swift's friends including Karlie Kloss, Lena Dunham and Selena Gomez, while **the single is actually a remix collaboration with hip hop artist Kendrick Lamar**, who also appears in the video.

I've been able to find the song on [iTunes/Apple Music](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/bad-blood/id907242701?i=907242709), though obviously if you purchase *1989* anywhere you'll have the song as well.

For further reference, it seems like the original/album version of the song clocks in at around 3:30, while the remix with Lamar is under 3:20 in duration.